# how to check table size from dump file in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, dump

I want to import an oracle dump
The .dmp file is of size :335 GB

I want to know three things:

- How can I know the size of the database before importing it?
- How much free space should I have in the server?
- Because I don't have as much space on the server, I want to import table by table. So how do I know the size that a table will take from the .dmp file?

To sum up:
I have the name of the table, 
is there a sql query that can tell me the size of this table from the dump file?

Comment: Was the dump produced by the old EXP utility or the new DATAPUMP EXPORT?

Comment: the dump was produced by the commande : expdp

Comment: Sorry but I have absolutely no idea whether that means anything